# featured product in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, php-5.4, jquery, featured-product

I'm working featured product slider and featured products also showing fine on home page.

my code is:

**featured-product-slider.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @see Easylife_FeaturedProducts_Block_Product_List
 */

$cms_id = $this->helper('featuredproducts')->getCurrentCmsPage();
if ( !$cms_id ) {
    $pageLayout = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate();
    if ( strpos($pageLayout, '2columns') ) {
        $grid_class = 'two_columns_' . Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/catalog/grid_columns_2col');
    } else {
        $grid_class = 'one_column_' . Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/catalog/grid_columns_1col');
    }
} else {
    if ( $cms_id == 'shopper_home' ) {
        $grid_class = 'one_column_' . Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/catalog/grid_columns_1col');
    } else {
        $grid_class = 'two_columns_' . Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/catalog/grid_columns_2col');
    }
}

$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$helper = $this->helper('featuredproducts/image');
$imgX = 252;
$imgY = $helper->calculateHeight($imgX);
$time = time() + mt_rand(0, 1000);
//$time = 1000;

//Mage::log($time);

?>

<?php if($_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div class="product-slider-container">
    <div class="clearfix title-container">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__($this->getBlockTitle());?></h2>
        <a href="#" class="jcarousel-prev-horizontal" id="shopper_carousel_prev<?php echo $time; ?>"></a>
        <a href="#" class="jcarousel-next-horizontal" id="shopper_carousel_next<?php echo $time; ?>"></a>
    </div>
    <ul id="featured_<?php echo $time; ?>" class="products-grid jcarousel-skin-tango clearfix <?php echo $grid_class; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item">

            <div class="regular">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php echo $this->helper('featuredproducts')->getLabel($_product);  ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX, $imgY) ?>" data-srcX2="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX*2, $imgY*2) ?>" width="<?php echo $imgX; ?>" height="<?php echo $imgY; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/ajax/cart')) : ?>
                            <?php if ( !($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product) || $_product->isGrouped()) ) { ?>
                                <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart ajax-cart" data-url="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart show-options" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                                <?php }  ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                            <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="hover">
                <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/ajax/cart')) : //quick view button ?>
                <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajax/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId()));?>' data-fancybox-group="gallery" class='fancybox quick-view' id='fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>'><?php echo $this->__('quick view')?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php echo $this->helper('featuredproducts')->getLabel($_product);  ?>
                    <?php
                    $_product->load('media_gallery');
                    $back_img = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'back');
                    if ( $back_img ) : ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image', $back_img->getFile())->resize($imgX, $imgY) ?>" data-srcX2="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image', $back_img->getFile())->resize($imgX*2, $imgY*2) ?>" width="<?php echo $imgX; ?>" height="<?php echo $imgY; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
                        <?php else : ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX, $imgY) ?>" data-srcX2="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX*2, $imgY*2) ?>" width="<?php echo $imgX; ?>" height="<?php echo $imgY; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                </a>

                <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/msrp/enabled')) :  ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);  ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->helper('featuredproducts/data')->priceFormat( $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()){ echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product); } ?>

                <div class="button-container">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                    <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/ajax/cart')) : ?>

                        <?php if ( !($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product) || $_product->isGrouped()) ) { ?>
                            <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart ajax-cart" data-url="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><em></em><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart show-options" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><em></em><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                            <?php }  ?>

                        <?php else: ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><em></em><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <span class="ajax_loading" id='ajax_loading<?php echo $_product->getId()?>'><img src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ajax-loader.gif')?>'/></span>

                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span>+</span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)) : ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span>+</span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[


    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var carouselID = '#featured_<?php echo $time; ?>';
        var jc = null;

        $('script', carouselID).detach();

        //line up carousel items
        var lineUp = function()
        {
            var height = 0;
            $('li.item', carouselID).each(function(i,v){
                $('div.product-info', this).css('height', 'auto');
                var h = $('div.product-info', this).height();
                if ( h > height ) {
                    height = h;
                }
            });
            $('li.item div.product-info', carouselID).height(height);
        }

        var mycarousel_initCallback = function(carousel)
        {
            if ( jc ) {
                return;
            }

            $('#shopper_carousel_next<?php echo $time; ?>').bind('click', function() {
                carousel.next();
                return false;
            });
            $('#shopper_carousel_prev<?php echo $time; ?>').bind('click', function() {
                carousel.prev();
                return false;
            });

            if (typeof $(carouselID).parent().swipe !== 'undefined'){
                $(carouselID).parent().swipe({
                    swipeLeft: function() { carousel.next(); },
                    swipeRight: function() { carousel.prev(); },
                    swipeMoving: function() {}
                });
            }

            jc = carousel;
        };

        var mycarousel_reloadCallback = function(carousel)
        {
            if ( !isResize('featured_<?php echo $time; ?>') ) return;
            carousel.list = $(carouselID);
            var li = $(carouselID).children('li');
            carousel.list.css(carousel.lt, "0px");
            carousel.list.css(carousel.wh, $(li.get(0)).outerWidth(!0) * li.size() + 100);
            carousel.first = 1;
            carousel.last = $(carouselID).parent().width() / $(li.get(0)).outerWidth(!0);
            lineUp();
        }

        $(carouselID).jcarousel({
            scroll: 1,
            initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
            reloadCallback: mycarousel_reloadCallback,
            buttonNextHTML: null,
            buttonPrevHTML: null
        });

    });

    //]]>
</script>

<?php endif ?>
```

and i have added the code cms = > Page = > Home Page = > Content = >

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/featured-products-slider.phtml"}}
```

the structure as below.

```
Home Page                                   << >>
=================================================
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|   P1  |   P2  |  P3   |   P4  |   P5  |   P6  |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
=================================================
```

P  = Product
<< = Previous

> > = Next

How to apply slider for this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any carousel for it. My favourite is [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/). You just need to check the demo, include JS and CSS for carousel as instructed in document, setup the structure as given and your slider should work.

Comment: Is it possible to specify `product_id` instead of `category_id`?

Comment: I am not clear what are you asking? how is it relevant with carousel?

Comment: No No, I'm asking from this line `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/featured-products-slider.phtml"}}`. Here `Category_id` is there right. Is it possible to specify `product_id="1,2,3"` instead of `category_id="3"`?

Comment: it completely depends on how you code it. If you want to retrieve product with id 1 2 3 you can do so and the same with category too

Comment: superb slideshow, really i like it i will try to implement this to my slider, and i will review the above comments.. Thank you..